# Display Pending Review in Product review

Tags: magento2, review, product-review

I want to display pending Review in the product review tab. But I can not found the proper file to remove or edit filter for pending review.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The review list which displayed on product view tab was defined here

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Review/Block/Product/View.php#L122-L135

```
public function getReviewsCollection()
{
    if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
        $this->_reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $this->getProduct()->getId()
        )->setDateOrder();
    }
    return $this->_reviewsCollection;
}
```

You could try to override the block and add filter to the

```
    ->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )
```

as what ever status you want

If you want to filter both approved and pending review

See

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Review/Model/ResourceModel/Review/Collection.php#L209-L225

```
 /**
 * Add status filter
 *
 * @param int|string $status
 * @return $this
 */
public function addStatusFilter($status)
{
    if (is_string($status)) {
        $statuses = array_flip($this->_reviewData->getReviewStatuses());
        $status = isset($statuses[$status]) ? $statuses[$status] : 0;
    }
    if (is_numeric($status)) {
        $this->addFilter('status', $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('main_table.status_id=?', $status), 'string');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

As a new overridden Collection we could write another filter like - This will define filter approved and pending to current collection. This was just and idea, you could use this filter directly to the overridden Block:

```
 /**
 * Add approved and pending status filter
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function addApprovedAndPendingStatusFilter()
{
    $statuses = [\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED, \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_PENDING];
    $inCond = $this->getConnection()->prepareSqlCondition('main_table.status_id', ['in' => $statuses]);

    $this->getSelect()->where($inCond);
    return $this;
}
```

Then back to the overridden Block we could call:

```
public function getReviewsCollection()
{
    if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
        $this->_reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->addApprovedAndPendingStatusFilter()->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $this->getProduct()->getId()
        )->setDateOrder();
    }
    return $this->_reviewsCollection;
}
```

Comment: But I want Both Approve and pending both

Comment: @KrunalPandya I've updated the answer, you could see how to add both statuses